# why this column expression throw the error Missing operand after last column?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to assign a `DataColumn` to `DataTable` dt, with the expression

```
  dc.Expression = string.Format( "{0} {1}", dt.Columns[6].ColumnName.Trim(), dt.Columns[5].ColumnName.Trim() );
```

Column order and index numbers are valid, but it thrown the following error

[image]

**"MIssing operand after MName operator"** `MName` is Middle Name column in my Database table. It should be concatenating two columns instead throws the error but i dont see any issues with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is perhaps not `string.Format` itself, but `dc.Expression = ...`.

Did you mean something like:

```
dc.Expression = string.Format( "{0} + {1}", // + or another operator
    dt.Columns[6].ColumnName.Trim(),
    dt.Columns[5].ColumnName.Trim() );
```

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "To concatenate a string, use the + character." Is it close to what you wanted?